# It's safe to send public-key along with signature

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, digital-signature, packet

I'm creating a blockchain, the transaction message have a sender and recipient fields which are just public keys (not address), and a RSA signature field. The signature is generated with sender's private key.
To verify message signature, you should use the message sender field. 
So, to change signature you should change sender field, and then message owner changes.

Is this safe? Does this prevent fake messages?

```golang
type TransactionBody struct {
    Sender    rsa.PublicKey `json:"sender"`
    Recipient rsa.PublicKey `json:"recipient"`
    ...
}
```

Comment: [what is the key distribution problem](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+is+the+key+distribution+problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate a digital signature, it is recommended that the public key of the sender, or its root CA in the case of using certificates, is available in a truststore of the recipient (that has been previously added by other means)

The verification process should verify that the public key of the signed message is available in the truststore to ensure that it comes from a trusted issuer. If not, anyone could generate a pair of keys and sign a valid message simply by including their public key.

In short you need a mechanism to validate that the public key is trusted, otherwise the digital signature will not increase the security level

Comment: So, recipient node must previously exchange signature public keys with sender node?

Comment: Yes, the recipient must have the sender's public key to verify that the digital signature comes from a trusted issuer. Alternatively you can use digital certificates issued by a trusted entity. In that case you just have to trust the root certificate, but it does not seem to be your case

Comment: And why my solution isn't safe? Since you can't pretend to be someone.

Comment: Suppose a man-in-the-middle captures the transaction message and replaces the `sender` field and signs with its own private key. The signature verification will be correct, so, how does the recipient validate that the message comes from a valid sender?

Comment: I see now. @pedrofb Solved. Thank you